# How to make a menu item accessible only to a specific user in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a menu item in my site that I want only the Admin of the site to be able to view.

I can't figure out how to get this done. Setting the permission to Special or Registered makes the menu item invisible. Event after the admin is logged in.

Some guidance on this matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want the menu item to visible to all users, but click or access only to admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user manager in admin backend make sure someone is flagged as "Super User".

Then when creating menus make sure you select Super User as to whom you want to display the menu link to.

You need to make sure you have a user group of Super User and an Access Level of Super User.

all the settings that need to be handled are located in the user manager of admin backend.

I recommend reading this link:
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_permissions_work_in_Joomla!_2.5

Hope this information helps you.